# Error during cdlib python package installation

Tags: python, pip, python-install

I am trying to install cdlib package in python but some error is occurring. Please help me to solve this problem. The error is given below

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: `'c:\python\python385\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\abc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iooglvcp\\gensim_fd954cc04c6c41f68764bcbd9eee0ddc\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\abc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iooglvcp\\gensim_fd954cc04c6c41f68764bcbd9eee0ddc\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bnge2snj\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python\python385\Include\gensim' Check the logs for full command output.`

Comment: Can you please paste the complete error output into your question?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using a dated version of **pip**?
If not, **pip3** should be able to install cdlib package

Comment: not working same error occurs.

Comment: can you please tell the exact error?

Comment: What version of **pip** are you using? You can check using ```pip --version```

Comment: pip 21.2.4 version and error is " Running setup.py install for gensim ... error"

Comment: If you are using a MacBook, you need *Xcode* to be able to install **cdlib** successfully. You need some requirements from Xcode.

Comment: I am using Windows 10